# Why updated structure variable not printing

Tags: c

This is my code in which if student marks is greater than 85,scholarship status will be changed to `sanctioned`, but after updating it is not printing

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct scholor
{
    char name[25];
    int  sem;
    int marks;
    char status;    

};
void sanction(int m, char *s)
{

    if(m>85)
    {
        char p[15]="sanctioned";
        char *r;
        r=p;
       while(*r!='\0')
       {
        *s=*r;     
        s++;
        r++;

       }
       *s='\0';
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct scholor s1;
    scanf("%s%d%d%s",&s1.name,&s1.sem,&s1.marks,&s1.status);
    sanction(s1.marks,&s1.status);
    printf("%s",s1.status);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`status` is a single char but you are storing a string into it, effectively doing out of bounds access ([*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). Change it to an *array* and then you'll be able to copy.

```
struct scholor
{
    char name[25];
    int  sem;
    int marks;
    char status[128];    
};
```

and adjust the calls and passing (since `status` is an array now -- its name gets converted into a pointer t its first element when passed to functions):

```
  scanf("%s%d%d%s",s1.name,&s1.sem,&s1.marks,s1.status);
  sanction(s1.marks,s1.status);
  printf("%s",s1.status);
```

Other suggestions:
1. Use a standard prototype for `main` such as: `int main(void)`
2. You could usr `strcpy` to copy the string as opposed to doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your struct should have status as a character array not a character .Moreover when you scanf an array dont write & before because the name itself points to the assdress of the first element.Your corrected program is :

```
struct scholor
{
  char name[25];
  int  sem;
  int marks;
  char status[16];
};
void sanction(int m, char *s)
 {
   if(m>85)
   {
     char p[15]="sanctioned";
     char *r;
     r=p;
    while(*r!='\0')
    {
      *s=*r;
      s++;
      r++;
    }
    *s='\0';      
  }
}
int main()
{
  struct scholor s1;
  scanf("%s%d%d%s",s1.name,&s1.sem,&s1.marks,s1.status);
  sanction(s1.marks,s1.status);
  printf("%s",s1.status);
}
```